# API for inline graphics in ipython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I made a small library in python that can generate graphics and I'd like to be able to display its object in ipython as with `%matplotlib inline`.

Is there some library that I could use to make this work in a simple way?
Bonus points if the display can be made interactive.

Comment: Here's the docs on how to do rich display of objects:http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please make it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on how to add rich display of your objects:
http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display

So long as you control the class definitions, you can add `_repr_*_` methods, e.g. `_repr_png_` or `_repr_html_`. Note that they're surrounded by *single* underscores, unlike Python's own magic `__repr__` method. Text data like HTML should be returned as a string, and binary data like PNG as bytes.

If you don't control the class definition, you can register formatters separately:

```
get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['image/png'].for_type(MyType, func)
```

[for_type() method docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html#IPython.core.formatters.BaseFormatter.for_type)